# Error message " Unreachable code detected" C-Sharp

Tags: c#, decrement

Why does the compiler give errormessage "unreachable code"? 
I would like to decrement the integer variable `nbElements`with  with -1 in this linked list.

```
public object Pop()
{
    if (StackEmpty())
        throw new Exception("Error: No nodes to pop from stack");

    object RemoveItem = headNode.Data; 

    if (headNode == tailNode)
        headNode = tailNode = null;
    else 
        headNode = headNode.Next;

    return RemoveItem;
    nbElements--;                 //Here is where the problem is
}
```

Comment: You `return` before decrementing the variable?

Comment: You cannot have a statement after the return like that. It is "unreachable code"

Comment: wrap your if conditional statement around `{ }else { }` if you are expecting to execute more than one statement in the else avoid `lzay formatting` in regards to `Code Blocks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a return statement, the function will return and any code in the function after the return statement is unreachable.

The simple solution is to change your function to have the return as the last line in your function.

```
public object Pop()
{
    if (StackEmpty())
    throw new Exception("Error: No nodes to pop from stack");
    object RemoveItem = headNode.Data; 
    if (headNode == tailNode)
        headNode = tailNode = null;
    else headNode = headNode.Next;
    nbElements--;  
    return RemoveItem;        
}
```

By the way, it's usually considered good practice to use curly braces around your if statement blocks. While not strictly necessary, it makes it clear what will be executed after the conditional and helps avoid adding code later that doesn't flow as expected. Here's what it should look like:

```
public object Pop()
{
    if (StackEmpty())
    {
        throw new Exception("Error: No nodes to pop from stack");
    }
    object RemoveItem = headNode.Data; 
    if (headNode == tailNode)
    {
        headNode = tailNode = null;
    }
    else
    {
        headNode = headNode.Next;
    }
    nbElements--;  
    return RemoveItem;        
}
```

At the very least, indent code!

Comment: IMO, good practice is just to add tabulations for one-line command in if and else. Braces are unnecessary

Comment: @lenden Unnecessary, but makes it absolutely clear what gets executed as part of the if statement and decreases the chance of introducing a bug later. Sure if you're a decent programmer then indenting is probably sufficient. But for new people (as the OP clearly is) then adding braces can save many headaches later.

Comment: it's hard to disagree :)

Answer (score 5):

```
headNode = headNode.Next;
```

goes in else, but

```
return RemoveItem;
```

isn't in else, so it returns. method stops and

```
nbElements--;
```

is unreachable

---

so, you can just swap "return RemoveItem;" and "nbElements--;"

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
public object Pop()
{
    if (StackEmpty())
    throw new Exception("Error: No nodes to pop from stack");
    object RemoveItem = headNode.Data; 
    if (headNode == tailNode)
        headNode = tailNode = null;
    else headNode = headNode.Next;
    nbElements--;  
    return RemoveItem;
}
```